# Custom function causes a 503 error after a couple of hours

Tags: functions

I have a custom function written in PHP for a Wordspress theme. When I initially wrote it, it worked exactly as expected (it returns the parents and grandparents etc of a term from its ID).

However, after a couple of hours, it started throwing up 503 errors. Why would this only happen after a while? Is there some sort of memory leak that builds up over time?

```
$ancestors = $terms[0]->term_id.GetAncestors($terms[0]->term_id,$include);

function GetAncestors($term_id,&$include) {
    $child_term = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );
    $parent_term = get_term( $child_term->parent, 'category' );
    $include.=','.$parent_term->term_id;
    if($parent_term->parent!=11) {GetAncestors($parent_term->term_id,$include);}
    return $include;
}
```

Is it the function itself that's causing the issue, or some way I'm using it, e.g. using a reference from an object as one of the variables?

Comment: This seems like a recursion of teadth to me. Can you confirm your function does not run infinitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the WordPress function [`get_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors), which

> Returns an array containing the parents of the given object.

To be exact an

> Array of ancestors from lowest to highest in the hierarchy

We can easily create a function to return a list by using `implode` to do so:

```
function wpse185971_get_ancestors_list(
    $object_id,
    $object_type = 'category',
    $separator = ','
) {
    $ancestors_array = get_ancestors( $object_id, $object_type );
    $ancestors_list  = implode( $separator, $ancestors_array );
    return $ancestors_list;
}
```

Comment: Again, I have made the mistake of writing a custom function when one already existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, I'd say you're running into a memory leak like you suggested, infinite recursive loop. You need to run checks for when the term either hits the top of the ancestry tree or errors out:

```
$ancestors = $terms[0]->term_id.GetAncestors( $terms[0]->term_id, $include );

function GetAncestors( $term_id, &$include ) {
    $child_term     = get_term( $term_id, 'category' );
    $parent_term    = get_term( $child_term->parent, 'category' );
    $include       .= ',' . $parent_term->term_id;

    if( ! empty( $parent_term ) && $parent_term->parent != 11 ) {       // We've reached the top - parent term_id is 0
        GetAncestors( $parent_term->term_id, $include );
    }

    return $include;
}
```

Eventually, `$parent->term_id` is going to equal `0` and we can't go up any further. We need to test for that and drop out once we hit it. I imagine if you turned on debugging you would see a ton of non-object errors regarding this function. The PHP function [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks for `null` and `0` so this should suffice.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in that code snippet, missing `&&` in your if statement